# Why Jetty boot script remove [SK][0-9] from base name?

Tags: shell, jetty

I read Jetty 9 boot script and found this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Startup script for jetty under *nix systems (it works under NT/cygwin too).

##################################################
# Set the name which is used by other variables.
# Defaults to the file name without extension.
##################################################
NAME=$(echo $(basename $0) | sed -e 's/^[SK][0-9]*//' -e 's/\.sh$//')

# To get the service to restart correctly on reboot, uncomment below (3 lines):
# ========================
# chkconfig: 3 99 99
# description: Jetty 9 webserver
# processname: jetty
# ========================
```

I wonder why we should remove S / K and numbers from `NAME`.

`/search/S2jetty.sh` => jetty

Anybody who can explain it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's trying to get the name from the init script that is currently running.

The links in the `/etc/init.d` directory all start with an `S` (for start) or a `K` (for kill) and a number (to control sort-order).

That letter+number combination is an artifact of the service system and not part of the name of the service in question so that prefix is being removed.

Comment: e.g. /etc/rc.d/rc4.d/S99local